# How to load text from csv file specify table schema using function "loadText"?

Tags: dolphindb

How to specify table schema when using function `loadText`  dealing with `csv` file?

When I loadText from `csv` file

`loadText("/data/myhome/test.csv")`,but the result are not what I expected, so How can I specify table schema when I load `csv` file using function `loadText`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

```
schematable=table(`ID`datetime`qty`price as name,`FLOAT`TIMESTAMP`LONG`DOUBLE as type)
tt=loadText("C:/DolphinDB/Data/t1.txt",,schema)
```

In the above example, I force the four loaded columns to be float, timestamp, long, and double.